# Staggered movement of Custom Cursor and another problem

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I have a custom cursor implemented for my website, but I want to add a delay to the bigger cursor. Therefore I added a `transition` property to it, but it seems very staggered.

Also, I have an animation on hover which doesn't seem to work properly. When I refresh my page and hover over a link, the first time it does nothing, but the second time I hover over it the animation works.

This is the CSS code:

```
.cursor{
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1000;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 0.5s ease; 
  transition-property: width, height;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}

.cursor2{
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border: 2px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 1000;
  pointer-events: none;
  transition: all 1ms linear; 
  transition-property: width, height;
  transform-origin: 100% 100%;
}
```

This is the JS:

```
let hover = document.querySelectorAll(".project-link");
let mouseCursor = document.querySelector(".cursor");
let mouseCursor2 = document.querySelector(".cursor2");

hover.forEach(el => {
    $(el).hover(function() {
            el.addEventListener("mouseover", function(){
                mouseCursor.classList.add("hover"),
                mouseCursor2.classList.add("hide");
            });
            el.addEventListener("mouseleave", function(){
                mouseCursor.classList.remove("hover"),
                mouseCursor2.classList.remove("hide");
            });
        });
    })

window.addEventListener("mousemove", cursor);

function cursor(e){
   mouseCursor.style.top = e.pageY + "px",
   mouseCursor.style.left = e.pageX + "px";
   mouseCursor2.style.top = e.pageY  + "px",
   mouseCursor2.style.left = e.pageX  + "px";
}
```

This is the CSS and the JS code I have got to make my custom cursor. This is all I have got but seems like Stack Overflow is making me write more so let me explain it further.

So when I hover over a link after refreshing the page the cursor doesn't animate. Basically, it doesn't add the required class, but if I hover over it the second time not refreshing at the same point of time the animation works and it adds the required class to the cursor div.

Comment: On `.cursor2` you have a transition duration of 1ms, which is a very small amount of time. Maybe you meant 1s? Also, take your `mouseover`/`mouseleave` listeners out of `(el).hover`.

Comment: COul,d you explain furthere?

Comment: And yes I even tried 1s duration its still very Staggered

Comment: By "staggered" I assume you mean the animation is abrupt (not smooth)? I'm not sure what properties you're trying to transition, without seeing your `.hover` and `.hide` classes. However, keep in mind that some properties cannot be animated, such as `display` and `visibility`. (You *can* animate `opacity`.)

Comment: No to add delay I added transition property but it is not Smooth basically what you said that is the reason I added "transition property" property in the css so the animation can be smooth atleast for the hover and hide